# What hotkeys to use to preview material node result?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

[image]

What hotkey should I use to quickly add "Viewer" node marked on the screenshot and preview result of my currently selected node?

Comment: Please use english language on bse. (Пожалуйста, используйте английский язык.)

Comment: Shift Ctrl LMB, assuming the **Node Wrangler** addon is enabled.